# On scroll animations using waypoints.js and animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want to have two elements animate on screen - one is text and the other image. Each time I scroll, I would like text A to fade out and be replaced with text B. Also, on each scroll, I would like image B to fade in and show beside image A.

I am new to jquery but it looks like waypoint.js and animate.css may be able to do what I want. Is this possible and how would you go about it?

Below is as far as I've got, I am trying to get the first part to work by changing the offset value. I think it isn't working as expected because there is not enough content on my page to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/nuq61wpd/

```
//CSS
.os-animation{
     opacity: 0;
}

.os-animation.animated{
    opacity: 1;
}

//HTML

<div class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeIn">
    <h1>This section will fade in</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>
<div class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeIn">
    <h1>This section will fade in</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
</div>


//JavaScript

function onScrollInit( items, trigger ) {
  items.each( function() {
    var osElement = $(this),
        osAnimationClass = osElement.attr('data-os-animation');

        var osTrigger = ( trigger ) ? trigger : osElement;

        osTrigger.waypoint(function() {
          osElement.addClass('animated').addClass(osAnimationClass);
          },{
              triggerOnce: true,
             offset: '90%'
        });
  });
}

onScrollInit( $('.os-animation') );
```